# create loop for array to get string from json String?

Tags: ios, iphone, json, nsdictionary

i need to display a Table View containing information from web service response i do no where iam doing wrong here my sample code

```
    NSData *data = [soapResultsString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];

    NSArray *array = [json allValues];

    for (int i=0; i<array.count; i++)
    {
        recordResults =NO;
        appDelegate.rateString  =[[[json valueForKey:@"plan_history"]valueForKey:@"rate"]objectAtIndex:i];
        appDelegate.descriptionString=[[[json valueForKey:@"plan_history"]valueForKey:@"description"]objectAtIndex:i];
        appDelegate.validityString=[[[json valueForKey:@"plan_history"]valueForKey:@"validity"]objectAtIndex:i];
        appDelegate.plantypeString=[[[json valueForKey:@"plan_history"]valueForKey:@"plantype"]objectAtIndex:i];

    }
```

i need to parse 4 values from plan_history like "rate","description","validity","plan type"
when i run my app i getting only one set of value in Table view . i.e my json string contains more than 20 records containing rate,description,validity and plan type
can u show me how to loop my json value and display all my records in Table View

Comment: Here in loop, you are re-writing the value each time the loop executes. And you will get only the last value. Either make `rateString`, `descriptionString` etc as `NSMutableArray`(not recommended) or make a `NSMutableArray` of dictionary or `NSObject` subclass that keeps an array of these values.

Comment: i cant get ur method,actually i parsed my value directly from webservices call. my values are printing good in Nslog but i dono to show my values in table view can u update some codes ?

Comment: @Harrypotter - you can create a class and take an array in appDelegate that will contain objects of that class. This way you can get all the records. Please check my answer below.

Comment: @Harrypotter are you still facing problem....

Answer (score 1):

You should eliminate those calls to `allValues` and `valueForKey`, as repeatedly calling those methods is very inefficient ways to tackle JSON parsing.

In one of your comments, you said that your JSON looked like:

```
{
    "plan_history": [
        {
            "rate": "₹1000",
            "description": "FullTalktimeTopupRs.1000FullTalktime",
            "validity": "Validity: 0\r",
            "plantype": "FullTalkTime"
        },
        {
            "rate": "₹508",
            "description": "FullTalktimeTopupRs.558morethanFullTalktime",
            "validity": "Validity: 2\r",
            "plantype": "FullTalkTime"
        }
    ]
}
```

(I wonder if there was something before this `plan_history` entry given your `allValues` reference, but unless you tell us otherwise, I'll assume this is what the original JSON looked like.)

If so, to parse it you would do:

```
NSMutableArray *results = [NSMutableArray array];

NSError *error;
NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&error];
NSArray *planHistory = json[@"plan_history"];

for (NSDictionary *planHistoryEntry in planHistory) {
    NSString *rateString  = planHistoryEntry[@"rate"];
    NSString *description = planHistoryEntry[@"description"];
    NSString *validity    = planHistoryEntry[@"validity"];
    NSString *planType    = planHistoryEntry[@"plantype"];

    // now do whatever you want with these four values.

    // for example, I'd generally create a custom object I defined elsewhere for these four values and add to results, e.g.

    [results addObject:[PlanHistoryEntry planHistoryEntryWithRate:rateString
                                                      description:description
                                                         validity:validity
                                                         planType:planType]];
}

// now do something with results, e.g. store it in some property in `appDelegate`, etc.
```

Where, `PlanHistoryEntry` might be defined like so:

```
@interface PlanHistoryEntry : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *rateString;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *planDescription;  // note, do not use `description` for property name
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *validity;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *planType;

+ (instancetype) planHistoryEntryWithRate:(NSString *)rateString
                          planDescription:(NSString *)planDescription
                                 validity:(NSString *)validity
                                 planType:(NSString *)planType;

@end

@implementation PlanHistoryEntry

+ (instancetype) planHistoryEntryWithRate:(NSString *)rateString
                          planDescription:(NSString *)planDescription
                                 validity:(NSString *)validity
                                 planType:(NSString *)planType
{
    PlanHistoryEntry *entry = [[self alloc] init];
    entry.rateString = rateString;
    entry.planDescription = planDescription;
    entry.validity = validity;
    entry.planType = planType;

    return entry;
}

@end
```

But I don't want you to get lost in the minutiae of this answer (because given the ambiguity of the question, I may have gotten some details wrong). The key point is that you should not be using `allValues` or `valueForKey`. Just navigate the JSON structure more directly as illustrated above.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
NSData *data = [soapResultsString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];

NSArray *rateArray = [[json objectForKey:@"plan_history"] objectForKey:@"rate"];
NSArray * descriptionArray = [[json objectForKey:@"plan_history"] objectForKey:@"description"];
NSArray * validityArray = [[json objectForKey:@"plan_history"] objectForKey:@"validity"];
NSArray * plantypeArray = [[json objectForKey:@"plan_history"] objectForKey:@"plantype"];
```

and use `rateArray`, `descriptionArray` etc.

Comment: will it return all values from array ?

Comment: As per your code, `objectForKey:@"rate"` and other key are array's. So you can use those arrays directly. If you can provide the json model, it will be more clear.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class storing your data as follows:

Something like:

```
planClass.h
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSString * rateString;
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSString * descriptionString;
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSString * validityString;
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSString * plantypeString;

plan.m
//@synthesize the properties of .h
```

Now in your .m file where you want to parse the data you can do something like:

```
    NSData *data = [soapResultsString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];

    NSArray *array = [json allValues];

    for (int i=0; i<array.count; i++)
    {
planClass *pc = [[planClass alloc]init];
        recordResults =NO;
        pc.rateString  =[[[json valueForKey:@"plan_history"]valueForKey:@"rate"]objectAtIndex:i];
        pc.descriptionString=[[[json valueForKey:@"plan_history"]valueForKey:@"description"]objectAtIndex:i];
        pc.validityString=[[[json valueForKey:@"plan_history"]valueForKey:@"validity"]objectAtIndex:i];
        pc.plantypeString=[[[json valueForKey:@"plan_history"]valueForKey:@"plantype"]objectAtIndex:i];
    [appDelegate.arrayPlan addObject:pc];
    }
NSLog(@"appDelegate.arrayPlan >> %@",appDelegate.arrayPlan); // you'll get array of planClass objects
```

You can now access the `arrayPlan` declared in `appDelegate` as follows:

```
for(id *obj in arrayPlan)
{
    planClass *pc = (planClass *)obj;
    NSLog("rate: %@",[pc valueForKey:@"rateString"]);
    NSLog("descriptionString: %@",[pc valueForKey:@"descriptionString"]);
    NSLog("validityString: %@",[pc valueForKey:@"validityString"]);
    NSLog("plantypeString: %@",[pc valueForKey:@"plantypeString"]);
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: can u explain how u got arrayPlan its bit confusing bro

Comment: you will have to declare it in your appDelegate. Instead of declaring separate NSString variables just declare NSMutableArray *arrayPlan; in appDel. Hope you got it.

Answer (score 0):

you need to store that value in fatalist control means in NSMutable array like this.

```
 NSData *data = [soapResultsString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
    NSMutableArray *arrayHistory = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    NSArray *array = [json allValues];

    for (int i=0; i<array.count; i++)
    {
        recordResults =NO;
        appDelegate.rateString  =[[[json valueForKey:@"plan_history"]valueForKey:@"rate"]objectAtIndex:i];
        appDelegate.descriptionString=[[[json valueForKey:@"plan_history"]valueForKey:@"description"]objectAtIndex:i];
        appDelegate.validityString=[[[json valueForKey:@"plan_history"]valueForKey:@"validity"]objectAtIndex:i];
        appDelegate.plantypeString=[[[json valueForKey:@"plan_history"]valueForKey:@"plantype"]objectAtIndex:i];

            [arrayHistory addObject:appDelegate.rateString];
            [arrayHistory addObject:appDelegate.descriptionString];
            [arrayHistory addObject:appDelegate.validityString];
            [arrayHistory addObject:appDelegate.plantypeString];
    }
```

Now use

> arrayHistory

to load data in table view

Comment: thanx for ur time bro, but still iam getting oly one records in all tablevie cell :(

Comment: now you have to use arrayHistry for putting data in Tableview. Please post your Tablevierw code so I will Explain you.

Comment: my json value is:"plan_history":[{"rate":"\u20b9 1000","description":"Full  Talktime  Topup  Rs.1000  Full  Talktime","validity":"Validity : 0\r","plantype":"Full TalkTime"},{"rate":"\u20b9 508","description":"Full  Talktime  Topup  Rs.558  more  than  Full  Talktime","validity":"Validity : 2\r","plantype":"Full TalkTime"}
here u can find that what i am expecting is

Comment: first i should identify the array count then i should display total number of records in table view thats it

Comment: wats your array name?  which was you used for displaying data in table view.